# Vue component opened in Ionic Vue Modal doesn't have $route and $router

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-component, vue-router

I'm creating app by using Vue Ionic and trying to change page by modal controller provided by ionic like the following code.

```
const modal = await this.$ionic.modalController.create({
  component: NewPageComponent
})
modal.present()
```

Then `NewPageComponent` is opened without problem in `<ion-modal></ion-modal>`.
But when I try to confirm $route and $router in NewPageComponent, NewPageComponent doesn't have these.

**NewPageComponent**

```
export default {
  created () {
    console.log(this.$route) // undefined
    console.log(this.$router) // undefined
  }
}
```

Vue Components opened in `<ion-modal></ion-modal>` don't seem to have `$route` and `$router`.
But others have these without problem.
For example I can see `$route` and `$router` in `App.vue`.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <v-app>
      <span>App</span>
    </v-app>
  <ion-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created () {
    console.log(this.$route) // this.$route exists
    console.log(this.$router) // this.$router exists
  }
}
</script>
```

Of course I have registered router in `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import Ionic from '@ionic/vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import './plugins/ionic.js'


Vue.use(Ionic)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router, // I have set router like this
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Is there any way to make Vue Components opened in `<ion-modal></ion-modal>` like NewPageComponent have `$route` and `$router`?

Comment: not sure where you got this code from but it is all wrong. I suggest you start with the ionic starter templates and the documentation on creating modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally Ionic uses another `Vue` instance. When you creating new modal it is placed in this instance without router that is registered in main app. I recommend you to use event bus pattern to communicate between components. It's pretty simple:

**EventBus.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

Then in main app you can listen to custom events:

**App.vue**

```js
import {EventBus} from './EventBus.js'
//...
created() {
  EventBus.$on('change-route', this.handleRouteChange)
  EventBus.$on('change-params', this.handleParamsChange)
},
beforeDestroy() {
  EventBus.$off('change-route', this.handleRouteChange)
  EventBus.$off('change-params', this.handleParamsChange)
},
methods: {
  handleRouteChange(page) {
    // here you can normally access this.$router
    this.$router.push(page)
  },
  handleParamsChange(params) {
    this.$router.push({params:params})
  }
},
```

**NewPageComponent.vue**

```js
import {EventBus} from './EventBus.js'
//...
methods: {
  changePage() {
    EventBus.$emit('change-page', '/new-page')

    // If you want to change page named route with params:
    // EventBus.$emit('change-page', {name:'product', params: {id: 10}})
  },
  updateParams() {
    EventBus.$emit('change-params', {id: 1010})
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works well when I want to change page from `NewPageComponent`. And is there good way to get parameters like `$route.params` from `NewPageComponent`?

Comment: @kooh take a look at my answer update. And if you want to get parameters you can pass it via props to modal component.

Comment: I got it. Using `props` looks good as you suggested. Thank you for your very kind explanation.